# How to know when a user moves the map in google map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a very simple app which has a single activity. Everytime I start the app, the camera is moved to my position. I have used a `LocationCallback` so everytime I change my position, the camera follows me:

```
locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        if (locationResult == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (Location location : locationResult.getLocations()) {
            currentLocation = location;
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude());
            if (isFollowing) {
                moveCamera(latLng, DEFAULT_ZOOM);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

As you can see, I have a Boolean `isFollowing` which is set by default to true. The problem is when the user tries moves the map to another point, the camera starts following again.

I also have added on click listener to the `LocationButton`, to be sure that in the moment in which the user clicks it, to be followed by the camera.

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() 
        isFollowing = true;
        return false;
    }
});
```

The question is, how can I set `isFollowing` to flase, so the camera stops following the user when he moved the map?

I found some posts here on SOF but only with `OnMyLocationChangeListener`, which I see is deprecated.

Comment: `isFollowing = false`? That variable is controlled by you, not the callback or map. If you don't want the user to be able to scroll through the map I don't think this is the right approach

Comment: @Chisko In fact I want the user to be able to scroll through the map but I  want to know when is doing this, to change that variable to false.

Comment: You can use any of the listeners listed on the [official docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future visitors, I have solved this problem by creating an invisible overlay in my layout file. I have added a simple `TextView` like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/invisible_text_view"/>
```

And then in my activity is have used `setOnTouchListener` and managed to change the value of the isFollowing variable to false, like this:

```
View invisibleTextView = findViewById(R.id.invisible_text_view);
invisibleTextView.bringToFront();
invisibleTextView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        isFollowing = false;
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveStartedListener` and `GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener`. See some examples [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/events).

In your case:

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveStartedListener(this);
mMap.setOnCameraIdleListener(this);

...

@Override
public void onCameraMoveStarted(int reason) {
    if (reason == OnCameraMoveStartedListener.REASON_GESTURE) {
        isFollowing = false;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraIdle() {
    // You may want to set isFollowing = true here
}
```

Comment: That's for your answer. I have tried it but it doesn't solve my problem because `onCameraMoveStarted` method is triggered even before is set `isFollowing = true` in `onMyLocationButtonClick`.